# WP7 Dynamic icons in ApplicationBar

Tags: dynamic, windows-phone-7, icons

Dynamic icons in ApplicationBar

It's possible to have dynamic icons in ApplicationBar with dynamic images loaded from url?
I tried this:

xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
```

cs:

```
var myIcon = ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton;
myIcon.IconUri = new Uri(iconImageUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
```

I'm getting error: Path cannot be absolute.

Answer (score 3):

Chage the second parametr to UriKind.Relative if the uri is relative - looks like this one:

```
"/Images/icon.png"
```

Comment: From a webpage? you can't. Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Please explain more, I know how to work with dynamic Bitmaps using HttpWebRequest, but I don't know how to assign dynamic Bitmap to ApplicationBar icon.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best idea is to save your image in isolated storage and call it with UriKind.Relative.

Comment: @Janci I suppose, you can download to Isolated Storage and use it as relative. When required, download the image in background. Even this way can serve dynamism. Are you looking for something different?

Answer (score 0):

Full setting appbar IconUri, see:

[image]