# Cimbalino appbar, annoying xaml warnings

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, cimbalino

Using it exactly as it is mentioned in manual, something like:

```xml
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:ApplicationBarBehavior>
        <behaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton Command="{Binding UpdateTaskCommand, Mode=OneTime}" IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/save.png" Text="Save Task" />
        <behaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton Command="{Binding DeleteTaskCommand, Mode=OneTime}" IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/delete.png" Text="DeleteTask" />
    </behaviors:ApplicationBarBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

but i'm getting xaml warnings "Path cannot be absolute". In general, it works, but warnings are annoying.

Images properties are set to "Content" and "Copy if newer" like mentioned here: [WP7 Dynamic icons in ApplicationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592236/wp7-dynamic-icons-in-applicationbar)

Comment: if you are you using `xmlns:behaviors="http://cimbalino.org"`, please change that to the full namespace instead! ALso, can you confirm that the sample code in GitHub gives you the same problems?

Comment: @PedroLamas i'm using full path, like **xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Behaviors;assembly=Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit"**. Also, i'll try to update code from Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so updating to the latest version (1.4.1 at the moment) solved the problem.
Link: https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit/downloads

Thanks, Pedro (dunno how to mark comment as right answer).

Comment: You can mark your own answer, Stack Overflow approves this behavior!